# How to Fetch Dynamic Multidimensional Array Elements and Display It Like a Path Name?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have dynamic multidimensional array that contain directory, sub-directory and file names in a project folder, key indicating a sub-directory name and value indicating file names, if a key equal to number indicating only file and then if a key hasn't any value indicating there is no file at all in a directory. The array look like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => index.php
    [src] => Array
        (
            [src2] => Array
                (
                    [src3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test_src3.php
                        )

                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test_src2.php
                        )

                )

            [0] => test_src.php
        )

    [src_test] => Array
        (
            [New Folder] => Array
                (
                )

            [src_test2] => Array
                (
                    [New Folder] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [src_test3] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

      [1] => test.php
)
```

The number of dimensions might be change based on sub directories that found in a folder path inputted by user (this program is used by a person in their local).

How could i fetch those array elements so that the result would be like this :

```
array(
    [0] => src/src2/src3/
    [1] => src_test/New Folder/
    [2] => src_test/src_test2/New Folder/
    [3] => src_test/src_test2/src_test3/
)
```

By the way i have a function to achieve this :

```
<?php 
    
    // Get specific element where the first index is 1 instead of 0
    function getAtPos($tmpArray,$pos) {
        $keys = array_keys($tmpArray);
        return array($keys[$pos-1] => $tmpArray[$keys[$pos-1]]);
    }

    // Get all Keys that has String type only
    function getKeyStr(array $mixed, $numbIdx){
        $results = [];
        $tmp = array_keys($mixed);
        $ii = 0;
        for ($i=1; $i <= $numbIdx; $i++) { 
            $keyArr = getAtPos($tmp, $i);
            if (is_string($keyArr[$ii])) {
                $results[] = $keyArr[$ii];   
            }
            $ii++;
        }
        return $results;
    }

    function getKeyPaths(array $tree, $glue = '/', $return_array = true){
        $paths = "";
        $result = [];

        foreach ($tree as $key => &$mixed) {
            if (is_array($mixed) && !is_int($key)) {                
                $path = $key . $glue;

                $retArrFalse = false;
                $jlhMixed = count($mixed);
                $getKeyStr = getKeyStr($mixed, $jlhMixed);
                $jlhKeyStr = count($getKeyStr);
                
                if ($jlhKeyStr < 2) {
                    $repeat = getKeyPaths($mixed, $glue, $retArrFalse);
                    $paths .= $path . $repeat;

                    if ($return_array) {
                        $paths .= "|";
                    }

                }elseif($jlhKeyStr > 1) {
                    for ($i=0; $i < $jlhKeyStr; $i++) { 
                        $idxAsso = $getKeyStr[$i];
                        $jlhKeySub = count($mixed[$idxAsso]);
                        $path2 = $idxAsso . $glue;
                        if ($jlhKeySub > 0) { 
                            $paths .= $path . $path2 . getKeyPaths($mixed[$idxAsso], $glue, $retArrFalse);
                            if ($return_array) {
                                $paths .= "|"; 
                            }
                        }else{
                            $paths .= $path . $path2;
                            if ($return_array) {
                                $paths .= "|"; 
                            }
                        } // END of if else
                    } // END of for loop
                } // END of elseif
            }
        } // END of foreach

        if ($return_array) {
            return explode("|", trim($paths, "|"));
        }
        return $paths;
    }
```

the above function does not result like what i expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => src/src2/src3/
    [1] => src_test/New Folder/
    [2] => src_test/src_test2/New Folder/src_test3/
)
```

How do i achieve this ?
Any help would be appreciated !

**UPDATE**

I have modified my function trying to solve this:

```
<?php

// To get spesific element on dynamic associative array
    function getAtPos($tmpArray,$pos) { // $pos is an index order starting with 1 instead of 0
        $keys = array_keys($tmpArray);
        return array($keys[$pos-1] => $tmpArray[$keys[$pos-1]]);
    }

    // Get key string type (associative) only in the given array
    function getKeyStr(array $mixed, $numbIdx){
        $results = [];
        $tmp = array_keys($mixed); // change key to element (as array number).
        $ii = 0;
        for ($i=1; $i <= $numbIdx; $i++) { 
            $keyArr = getAtPos($tmp, $i);
            if (is_string($keyArr[$ii])) {
                $results[] = $keyArr[$ii];   
            }
            $ii++;
        }
        return $results; // Return all second dimension sub-keys of the given array (parent)
    }
    
    // EDITED !
    function getKeyPaths2(array $tree, $glue = '/', $return_array = true, $goToIfElse = false, $saveSameParent = []){ 
        $paths = "";
        $result = [];
        $iFor = 0;

        foreach ($tree as $key => &$mixed) {

            if (is_array($mixed) && !is_int($key)) {
                
                $path = $key . $glue;

                $retArrFalse = false;
                $jlhMixed = count($mixed);
                $getKeyStr = getKeyStr($mixed, $jlhMixed); // Contain sub-keys of the second dimension of the parent
                $jlhKeyStr = count($getKeyStr); // Count number of sub-keys of second dimension of parent

                if ($goToIfElse !== false) {
                    $jlhKeyStr = $goToIfElse;
                    $iFor++;
                    
                    unset($mixed);
                    $mixed = $tree;
                    
                    $jlhMixed = count($mixed);
                    $getKeyStr = getKeyStr($mixed, $jlhMixed); // Contain sub-keys of the second dimension of the 
                    $jlhKeyStr = count($getKeyStr); // Count number of sub-keys of second dimension of parent
                }

                if ($jlhKeyStr < 2) {

                    $repeat = getKeyPaths2($mixed, $glue, $retArrFalse);
                    $paths .= $path . $repeat;

                    if (!$return_array && $jlhKeyStr < 1) {
                        $paths .= "|"; 
                    }

                }elseif($jlhKeyStr > 1) { 

                    for ($i=$iFor; $i < $jlhKeyStr; $i++) { 

                        $idxAsso = $getKeyStr[$i];
                        $jlhKeySub = count($mixed[$idxAsso]);
                        $path2 = $idxAsso . $glue;

                        if ($jlhKeySub > 0) { 

                            $paths .= $path  . $path2;
                            
                            // TEST
                            $pecah = explode("|", $paths);
                            $saveSameParent[0] = end($pecah);

                            if ($return_array) {
                                $paths .= "|"; 
                            }
                            $paths .= $path  . $path2 . getKeyPaths2($mixed[$idxAsso], $glue, $retArrFalse, $jlhKeyStr, $saveSameParent); 
                            
                            if ($return_array) {
                                $paths .= "|"; 
                            }
                        }else{

                            if ($goToIfElse !== false) {
                                $paths .= $path;
                                $paths .= "|"; 

                                $paths .= $saveSameParent[0] . $path2;
                                $paths .= "|"; 

                            }else{
                                $paths .= $path . $path2;
                            }
                            
                            if ($return_array || $goToIfElse !== false) {
                                $paths .= "|"; 
                            }

                        } // END of if else
                    } // END of for loop
                } // END of elseif
            }
        } // END of foreach

        if ($return_array) {
            return explode("|", trim($paths, "|"));
        }
        return $paths;
    }
```

But this only works with my example array that i showed above.

If the given array like this, this would not work:

```
<?php
     $tree = [];
    $tree[0] = "index.php";
    $tree["src"]["src2"]["src3"][0] = "test_src3.php";
    $tree["src"]["src2"][0][0] = "test_src2.php";
    $tree["src"][0] = "test_src.php";
    $tree["src_test"]["New Folder"] = array();
    $tree["src_test"]["src_test2"]["New Folder"] = array();
    $tree["src_test"]["src_test2"]["src_test3.1"] = array();
    $tree["src_test"]["src_test2"]["src_test3.2"] = array();

    $tree["src_test"]["src_test2"]["src_test3.1"]["src_test3.1.1"] = array();
    $tree["src_test"]["src_test2"]["src_test3.2"]["src_test3.2.1"]["src_test3.2.2"]["src_test3.2.3"] = array("test_src4.php", "test_src5.php");
```

The result would be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => src/src2/src3/
    [1] => src_test/New Folder/
    [2] => src_test/src_test2/
    [3] => src_test/src_test2/New Folder/src_test3.1/New Folder/src_test3.1/src_test3.1.1/src_test3.1.1/
    [4] => New Folder/src_test3.2/New Folder/src_test3.2/src_test3.2.1/src_test3.2.1/src_test3.2.2/src_test3.2.3/
    [5] => src_test3.1/src_test3.2/src_test3.1/src_test3.2/src_test3.2.1/src_test3.2.1/src_test3.2.2/src_test3.2.3/
)
```

Comment: If there is something in the question has not clear yet, you can ask.